# JavaScript Function inside the loop

Tags: javascript, function, jslint

Can someone explain to me why JSLint complains about "Function inside the loop" with this example:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
        t.progressBars[t.current].update(buttons[i].getAttribute("data-value"));
      }
    })(i);
  }
```

But dosen't when I change it to:

```
function makeHandler(i)
  {
    return function() {
        t.progressBars[t.current].update(buttons[i].getAttribute("data-value"));
      }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

      buttons[i].onclick = makeHandler(i);

  }
```

I don't quite understand as it seems that with each loop iteration new function object has to be returned, even though it happens inside of `makeHandler()` function. Why the second example is ok with JS linters?

Comment: 2nd example binds i with the callback. 1st one doesn't. you will have all i values equal to n in first example. where second one will have 0 to n-1.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh - Look again. The first one is an IFFE and does the same binding.

Comment: It's just an under-informed warning by jsLint.  People give its warnings more credit than it deserves.  It can warn you about things you shouldn't be doing, but everything it warns about is not a problem or even necessarily something that should be changed.

Comment: @TedHopp: Oh god. am i missing something? [see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9toxka9o/). doesnt bind.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh - you're alerting the number `1`, not `i`.  That doesn't show anything.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh - Um, you're calling `alert(1)`; try calling `alert(i)`

Comment: @mithunsatheesh You have a typo in the fiddle alert(1) should be alert(i) I think

Comment: @TedHopp - oh. yes. sorry for that. thanks for help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two examples are not equivalent.

In the first, you are creating an anonymous function and calling it on every loop.

The inner function (the click event handler) is fine - you're assigning a new function - but it's the anonymous outer function that is inefficient in this context. In your second example the outer function is refactored out of the loop where is it only created once, instead of `buttons.length` times.

Answer (score 8):

Quoting from [linterrors](http://linterrors.com/js/dont-make-functions-within-a-loop),

> ```
> var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass"), i;
> for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
>     (function (iCopy) {
>         "use strict";
>          elems[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
>             this.innerHTML = iCopy;
>          });
>     }(i));
> }
> ```
>
> What we have now captures the value of `i` at each iteration of the loop. This happens because JavaScript passes arguments to functions by value. This means that `iCopy` within the capturing function is not related to i in any way (except for the fact that they happen to have the same value at that point in time). If `i` changes later (which it does - on the next iteration of the loop) then `iCopy` is not affected.
>
> This will work as we expect it to but the problem now is that the JavaScript interpreter will create an instance of the capturing function per loop iteration. It has to do this because it doesn't know if the function object will be modified elsewhere. Since functions are standard JavaScript objects, they can have properties like any other object, which could be changed in the loop. Thus by creating the function in the loop context, you cause the interpreter to create multiple function instances, which can cause unexpected behavior and performance problems. To fix the issue, we need to move the function out of the loop:

I would have liked to use `Array.prototype.forEach` here, like this

```
buttons.forEach(function(curButton) {
    curButton.onclick = function(e) {
        t.progressBars[t.current].update(curButton.getAttribute("data-value"));
    };
});
```

Comment: Using an IIFE to create a closure is a standard problem solving mechanism in loops.  I don't see a problem at all.  If you don't need a closure, the code could be moved to an externally defined function so it's a function call instead of an IIFE, but that has some tradeoffs (no access to parent scope variables), extra symbols declared, code not inline for readability, etc...

Comment: @jfriend00 Agreed. I was just pointing out what jsLint thinks about code like this :-)